# The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding - HTTP Error 500.19

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I was getting an error `"Request Entity Too Large error- WCF Service"`.

So that I added below lines in the **web.config**. It is working fine after adding in DEV. I have sent it to the same in **PRODUCTION**.

I am getting an error "`The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding....`"

[image]